# Execute file in resourses folder without copying it to disk

Tags: c#

I have an executable file in the resources folder. I am able to run that file by writing it to the disk then locating the file and use the Process.Start method to run the executable. Here is an example of how I do this:

[image]

How can I execute the file without writing it to the disk. Is there a way I can execute the file from memory? Or maybe execute it directly from the resources folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  One of the very hard requirements of Windows, an executable *must* exist on disk.  It is fundamental to its architecture.  Slowing down the malware authors is a happy side-effect.  Google "memory mapped file" if you want to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a .NET exe try `Assembly.Load(byte[])`. Be wary of CAS though.

Comment: That wouldn't run the program though. no?

Comment: Ofcourse it wouldn't, you need reflection to find and invoke the entry point.